# How can I move to the next search result in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I alt-double-click on a method name in Xcode, I get taken to the method documentation. Often, there are multiple methods with the same name (one example is scrollEnabled, which gives me 9 results). If the one Xcode shows me isn't in the class I want, how can I get to the next result? The back button doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the listing view of the documentation window hidden. Normally above the documentation pane there is a list of the matches for your query (similar to the pane at the top of the editor part - where you can do Command-Shift-E to toggle that, but it doesn't work for some reason in the Docs window).

Anyway, drag the top part of your pane down to see the listing.

Hope that was clear enough.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. The bar was hidden, I just had to drag it out from under where it says "Starts With". Thanks!